# css turn right side of an image into an arrow

Tags: html, css

I have a rectangular sprite image that is 120px x 40px.  When someone select the image I want the right side of the selected image to turn into an arrow pointing right.
I know how to use border-radius but that gives a curves whereas I want a point.
Using css how would I turn the right side of an image into a arrow?

Thanks

Basically I want to perform a border-radius only on the right side, but instead of curved pointed like an arrow.

```
.selected {
 -webkit-border-radius: 0px  25px 25px 0px;
 border-radius: 0px  25px 25px 0px;
}
```

[image]

Comment: use `transform: rotate(xxdeg);` if you want to rotate the image

Comment: Please provide a little sample of HTML / CSS. We can create an overlay with pseudo elements. [Something like this example](http://jsbin.com/xuxuhe/1/edit)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can keep the white background here is a very simple solution:

[jsFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/jeremyhawes/z3q02gdx/2/)

Run the image in the background of the following example.

**HTML**

```
<div class="container"></div>
<div class="container"></div>
<div class="container"></div>
```

**CSS**

```
.container {
    background: #333;
    width: 200px;
    height: 60px;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.container:hover::after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    width: 70px;
    height: 30px;
    background: #fff;
    top: -20px;
    right: -20px;
    z-index: 1;
    transform: rotate(45deg);
}
.container:hover::before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    width: 70px;
    height: 30px;
    background: #fff;
    bottom: -20px;
    right: -20px;
    z-index: 1;
    transform: rotate(-45deg);
}
```

Comment: I have a jquery click event assigned to the div's.  When click it will apply the selected class.  The selected class applies the css to make the arrow.

Comment: The only change you should make then is targeting the element based on that class. For example element.active::after and element.active::before, though replace the .active with whatever the correct jQuery class is and also make sure to give the element a position relative.

Comment: That did it.  I just removed the hover and it works great.  Thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I do not know, i understood your question, but i think, what you want to achive, can be done by jQuery and `css` function with `background-position`

Answer (score 0):

Basically, if you want to use a CSS Sprite image, `background-position` will indeed do it.

You may want to have a `<div>` positionned over your image, that will be displayed on hovering (CSS `:hover`) or click (jQuery `click` event) the image, depending on what you meant by "selecting" it.

Here is an example for [hovering case](http://jsfiddle.net/ut7ae8gv/3/) (pure CSS) and here is an [example for the clicking case](http://jsfiddle.net/ut7ae8gv/4/) (with 3 lines of jQuery).